# Why is the keyword "typename" needed before qualified dependent names, and not before qualified independent names?

Tags: c++, templates, typename

```
class A
{
   static int iterator;
   class iterator
   {
      [...]
   };
   [...]
};
```

I (think I) understand the reason why `typename` is needed here:

```
template <class T>
void foo() {
   typename T::iterator* iter;
   [...]
}
```

but I don't understand the reason why `typename` is not needed here:

```
void foo() {
   A::iterator* iter;
   [...]
}
```

Can anyone explain?

---

### EDIT:

The  reason why the compiler does not have a problem with the latter, I found to be answered well in a comment:

*in the case of `A::iterator` I don't see why the compiler wouldn't confuse it with the `static int iterator` ? - xcrypt*

*@xcrypt because it knows what both `A::iterator`s are and can pick which one depending on how it is used – Seth Carnegie*

---

The reason why the compiler needs `typename` before the qualified dependent names, is in my opinion answered very well in the accepted answer by Kerrek SB. Be sure to also read the comments on that answer, especially this one by iammilind:

"T::A * x;, this expression can be true for both cases where T::A is a type and T::A is a value. If A is a type, then it will result in pointer declaration; if A is a value, then it will result in multiplication. Thus a single template will have different meaning for 2 different types, which is not acceptable."

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Why did you change the tags? Is template-meta-programming not the correct term then? I thought "templates" could mean different things such as some predefined text etc?

Comment: No template metaprogramming involves using templates to generate code at compile time, which you're not doing here. You can read more on the insanity of [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_meta-programming) if you wish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords - related

Comment: @AndrewMarshall So you're claiming that `template<class T> void foo() {[...]}` will not generate code at compile time when used somewhere in the code?

Comment: @xcrypt - I don't think he's claiming that, but it's not meta programming in the usual sense of it. Meta programming can be though of as "doing stuff you can't do with Java generics" - it's exploiting the fact that templates are basically Turing complete.

Comment: @xcrypt Read about what template metaprogramming *actually* is and you'll see why what you're doing isn't it. You're not doing any sort of computations at compile time through the use of templates.

Comment: @awoodland Also known as "stuff Bjarne never intended to be done" :P

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A *name* in C++ can pertain to three different tiers of entities: Types, values, and templates.

```
struct Foo
{
    typedef int A;                   // type
    static double B;                 // value
    template <typename T> struct C;  // template
};
```

The three names `Foo::A`, `Foo::B` and `Foo::C` are examples of all three different tiers.

In the above example, `Foo` is a complete type, and so the compiler knows already what `Foo::A` etc. refer to. But now imagine this:

```
template <typename T> struct Bar
{
    T::A x;
};
```

Now we are in trouble: what is `T::A`? if `T = Foo`, then `T::A = int`, which is a type, and all is well. But when `T = struct { static char A; };`, then `T::A` is a *value*, which doesn't make sense.

Therefore, the compiler demands that *you* tell it what `T::A` and `T::B` and `T::C` are *supposed* to be. If you say nothing, it is assumed to be a value. If you say `typename`, it is a typename, and if you say `template`, it is a template:

```
template <typename T> struct Bar
{
    typename T::A x;    // ah, good, decreed typename

    void foo()
    {
        int a = T::B;   // assumed value, OK

        T::template C<int> z;  // decreed template
        z.gobble(a * x);
    }
};
```

Secondary checks such as whether `T::B` is convertible to `int`, whether `a` and `x` can be multiplied, and whether `C<int>` really has a member function `gobble` are all postponed until you actually instantiate the template. But the specification whether a name denotes a value, a type or a template is fundamental to the syntactic correctness of the code and must be provided right there during the template definition.

Comment: Pretty good explanation, I just have one question: Would you say that compilers have to demand this, or is it just something that makes it easier for the people who write the compiler? I don't know a whole lot about compilers, but I think it should be possible for the compiler to figure out itself? It could just give an error when the template gets compiled at instantiation (when used at some part in the code)?

Comment: @xcrypt: It's absolutely necessary. How else would you parse `X::A < X::B > X::C`?

Comment: @Kerrek: Well, you don't, like MSVC. :P (Disclaimer: I don't actually know if MSVC would or would not parse that.)

Comment: @KerrekSB copy paste, and if it's not correct, display an error? However I can see that this way it is not able to check whether the definition of your template before instantiation makes sense, but it should be possible, no?

Comment: @xcrypt, there are several aspects, a compiler needs to consider. For example, `T::A * x;`, this expression can be true for both cases where `T::A` is a type and `T::A` is a value. If `A` is a type, then it will result in pointer declaration; if `A` is a value, then it will result in multiplication. Thus a single `template` will have different meaning for 2 different types, which is not acceptable. Thus, we need to mention explicitly if it's a type or not.

Comment: @xcrypt: Well, if you think more about it, you can probably come up with syntax which is rather more ambiguous and where you can't just try and see what the best match is... but I don't have a good example ready, I'm afraid. Maybe someone can chip one in. [Ah, this already happened.]

Comment: @iammilind Aha, great explanation! I've always learned at uni that templates get copy-pasted at compile-time, but I see this is not entirely the case. Thank you :)

Comment: @xcrypt: That's not entirely wrong, but "compile time" can be a very long time ... especially in C++!

Answer (score 2):

Because in the nontemplate foo, you are doing a valid multiplication operation (assuming you declared `iter` before that use).  Try to omit the star, and you will get a compiler error. The int hides the class.

The typename keyword does *not* prevent that hiding. Only gcc implements it incorrectly to do so. So if you try to instantiate your function template with `A` as the type, then you *will* get a compile error, because the name specified afteer typenake *will* refer to a nontype on any standard conformant compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler doesn't know what `T::iterator` is until the template is instantiated, it doesn't know whether `iterator` is a class variable, a type, a function, or what. You need to tell it that it is a type by using `typename`.

Comment: and in the other case, it does know what we want? And I don't see the harm of the compiler not knowing what it is before it is instantiated, isn't that the whole philosophy behind templates?

Comment: @xcrypt yes, because it knows what `A` is and therefore what `A::iterator` is. As for why it works this way, it's because the designers of the language just chose to make it that way. Rather than wait, they just make the programmer tell them what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @xcrypt It doesn't know what `T` is, but it does need to know what the *role* of `T::iterator` in the statement/expression actually is.

Comment: in the case of `A::iterator` I don't see why the compiler wouldn't confuse it with the `static int iterator` ?

Comment: @xcrypt If it knows exactly what `A` is it can lookup exactly what `A::iterator` is. If it doesn't know what `A` is it's an error outside of template code and ambiguous inside of template code.

Comment: @xcrypt because it knows what both `A::iterator`s are and can pick which one depending on how it is used