# The 'typename' word in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I am reading a C++ code and I came across the use of the keyword `typename` in the middle of the class 
definition.

Here is the class definition and the keyword is used in the protected section.

```
template<typename CVertex, typename CEdge, typename CFace, typename CHalfEdge>
class CBoundary
{
    typedef CLoop<CVertex,CEdge, CFace, CHalfEdge> TLoop;

public:

    CBoundary( CBaseMesh<CVertex,CEdge,CFace,CHalfEdge> * pMesh );

    ~CBoundary();

    std::vector<TLoop*> & loops() 
    { 
        return m_loops; 
    } 

protected:

    CBaseMesh<CVertex,CEdge,CFace,CHalfEdge> * m_pMesh;

     typename std::vector<TLoop*> m_loops;

    void _bubble_sort( std::vector<CLoop<CVertex, CEdge, CFace, CHalfEdge>*> & loops);
};
```

Is this the same as the `typedef` keyword? There seem to be a couple of related questions like 
[so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584431/why-is-the-keyword-typename-needed-before-qualified-dependent-names-and-not-b) but I did not really understand the explanation there.

In fact since typename is one of the SO tags I will list the explanation which I did not understand

> typename is a keyword in the C++ programming language with two
>   meanings. First, it can be used to declare type arguments inside a
>   template declaration, and is synonymous with "class." Second, it can
>   be used to indicate that a dependent name refers to a type. A common
>   cause of errors in C++ code is the omission of an essential typename.

It looks like I am dealing with the second use here. But I don't understand what "dependent name"
means here.

I am just a beginner in template metaprogramming with C++ so a simple explanation of the use 
in the class above would be very helpful.

Comment: I think the word `typename` in `typename std::vector<TLoop*> m_loops;` is wrong, or at least unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words, "dependent name" in a template code is some type which is constructed within the definition of the template.

In your example, the types CVertex, CEdge, CFace, CHalfEdge are template *parameters*. All other names which are declared with usage of the parameters are *dependent*.

They can be type names but can be something else, e.g. name of the functions or variables. Compiler has to understand, whether a given dependent name is a type or a variable. It is actually compiler-dependent. To help the compiler, you add "typename" to indicate that this identifier is a type.

Imagine, that your code does not have `#include <vector>` but instead uses forward declaration:
`namespace std { template<class T, class Alloc=allocator<T> > class vector; }`

Then compiler has no idea which names within class vector are types and which are member names. It only knows that `vector` is a type.

For example, in the code `typename std::vector<TLoop*> m_loops;` most likely the word `typename` can be omitted for most compilers because they know that vector is a type.

However, the code `std::vector<TLoop*>::const_iterator` will sure require `typename`: `for (typename std::vector<TLoop*>::const_iterator it = loops().begin(); ...`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef T type;
    static T static_var;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    typename T::type var;
};
```

Imagine I instantiate `B<A<int>>`. The compiler will, effectively, try to substitute `A<int>` wherever I have written `T` in the second definition. The trouble is, when it gets to `T::type`, it doesn't know whether I'm referring to a nested type, or a static variable -- both declarations look the same.

Sometimes it can disambiguate by the context in which it is used, but often it can't. Where it can't, you have to tell it that `T::thing` is the name of a type, by using the `typename` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you showed, `typename` is a synonym for `class`. It means the parameter is a type.

It has other uses in other contexts however. Whenever `T1` depends on a template parameter and you want to reference `T1::T2`, you have to say `typename T1::T2` instead, to let the compiler know `T2` is a type -- otherwise it's treated like a function or a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I think of typename when used with templates is that it is specifying that the identifier coming after the typename keyword is a type.  The result is that when a template is used and a type is specified in the template arguments, C++ knows that it is a type and will expand the template correctly.  It is a way of saying unambiguously that some identifier in the template argument list is a type such as a class name or a built in type or whatever.

There appear to be certain circumstances when the context may not be clear that a type specified in the template argument is a type so typename is used to make it unambiguous.

For instance see this [wikipedia article on typename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename)

And this article may be of assistance as well, [Template and typename keywords in C++](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html).