# How to use Boost d_ary_heap?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, binary-heap

I'm trying to use the Boost d_ary_heap but I cannot figure out how to get the handle for a pushed element. In my case, I will need to update the value in a later iteration, so I need that handle. I was able to do it with the Fibonacci heap but in this case it looks much more complex.

This is what I have so far:

```
struct compare_cells_d_ary {
inline bool operator()
(const myType * c1 , const myType * c2) const {

    return c1->getValue() > c2->getValue(); // I want a min heap.        
}
};


class MyHeap {

typedef typename boost::heap::d_ary_heap<const myType *, boost::heap::mutable_<true>, boost::heap::arity<2>, boost::heap::compare<compare_cells_d_ary>>::handle_type handle_t;

protected:
    boost::heap::d_ary_heap<const myType *, boost::heap::arity<2>, boost::heap::mutable_<true>, boost::heap::compare<compare_cells_d_ary>> heap_;  
    std::vector<handle_t> handles_; // I store the handles in an specific order.

public:
 /****/
    void push (const myType * c) {
        handles_[c->getIndex()] = heap_.push(c);
    }

 /****/
};
```

The push function is how I use it in the Fibonacci heap, which returns a handle_type. But in this case I cannot understand what it is supposed to return (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/heap/d_ary_heap.html#idp52218904-bb)

Any help in how to get the handle when pushing is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared your heap as mutable, the `push` operation is supposed to return the `handle_t` you typedefed as the `handle_type`:

```
mpl::if_c< is_mutable, handle_type, void >::type push(value_type const & v);
```

In the respect of obtaining the handle, your code is fine. To simplify a bit to make it clearer:

```
void push (const myType * c) {
    handle_t handle = heap_.push(c);
    handles_[c->getIndex()] = handle;
}
```

As a side-note, you should have a typedef for the heap instead of repeating it in the declarations, and the `typename` is superfluous (at least in the snippet you posted in the question.)

Comment: Thank you, now it compiles. I have to say that I already tried that but maybe was because of the typename you mention, or something, because it was complaining about that push returned void and I wasn't ignoring the return (??). Thank you for the advice, now I am testing if it works. However, I do not see why the typename is superfluous (the more I read about it the more confused I am).

Comment: Also, for the Fibonnaci heap the push returns a handle_type, howver, all this: mpl::if_c< is_mutable, handle_type, void >::type  what is it  exactly? Because in my code I am doing that equal to my handle_t

Comment: The typename is superfluos because there is no template type here that might be ambiguous for the compiler to resolve. As for the type definition it roughly interprets as: if the heap was defined as mutable, ie with `boost::heap::mutable_<true>`, have `handle_type` as the return type of push, otherwise (if the heap is immutable) have the push  return `void`.

Comment: Here's a good explanation regarding `typename`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8584507/3099074