# How to use a C++ pointer of abstract type to point to a concrete class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, point-cloud-library

I'm working with the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) and I'm trying to avoid repeating the following behaviour:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr filter(PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr input_cloud) {
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    subclass.setInputCloud(input_cloud);
    subclass.filter(*cloud_filtered);
    return cloud_filtered;
}
```

I hoped to use something based on this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm) and along the lines of:

```
pcl::Filter<PointXYZRGB>* f;
pcl::Subclass<PointXYZRGB> s; //where s is an implementation of f
f = &s;

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr filter(PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr input_cloud) {
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    f->setInputCloud(input_cloud);
    f->filter(*cloud_filtered);
    return cloud_filtered;
}
```

However this will not compile as `f does not name a type` as reported by the compiler.

I assume is this due to [pcl::Filter](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_filter.html) being an abstract class?

Is this approach valid for an example class such as [pcl::VoxelGrid](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_voxel_grid.html) or is there an alternative?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: I smell [missing `typename`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584431/why-is-the-keyword-typename-needed-before-qualified-dependent-names-and-not-b)

Comment: Are you trying to do `f = &s;` outside of a function?

Comment: usually you got this error when the compiler can't find the class, it is very normal to have f as an abstract class to me I think the problem is in the include or something like that, are u sure that your include is in the right place ?

Comment: Yes! I did not realise that was illegal outside of a function. I am no C++ scholar so I apologise for that. I put `f = &s;` in the constructor and it is working as expected. Many thanks to all. @aschepler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `f = &s;` should be moved to within a function.

In this case it was moved to within the constructors of derived subclasses.

**Credit and thanks for the answer to user, aschepler**