# Using typedef inside template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'am newbie in c++, and i'm trying to write an additional template which contains type char or type int. After that I want to use this template in other template to select the type of data, depending of input data padding.

```
template <bool isPadding>
class PaddingTemplate;

template <>
class PaddingTemplate<false>
{
public:
    typedef char Type;
};

template <>
class PaddingTemplate<true>
{
public:
   typedef int Type;
};

template <class T, bool Padding = ((sizeof(T) % sizeof(int)) == 0)>
class ObjectComparator
{
private:
    typedef     PaddingTemplate<Padding>    PaddingTrick;
    typename    PaddingTrick::Type          DataType;

    DataType Shadow[sizeof(T) / sizeof(DataType)];
};
```

I get this compiler error

[Compiler msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93FaF.jpg)

How to solve the problem and automate the choice of data type depending on data padding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataType` isn't actually a type. It's a instance of `PaddingTrick::Type`, which is why the next line is giving you an error. You need to do:

```
typedef typename PaddingTrick::Type DataType;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Could you explain more how the combination of typename and typedef works in this code?

Comment: @Ilia, all `typename` means is that the dependent name you are looking for is a type: it could be a value or even a template. If you use `typename Class::type data`, it means you want to construct an object of that type. `typedef typename Class::type type` means you want an alias to it. 

As to why `typename` is needed, this is a great answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584507/4131059

Comment: What a cool programming language С++! Thanks again  and a big greetings from Russia!

Comment: Consider using `using`, I find it makes type definitions clearer:  `using DataType=typename PaddingTrick::Type;`