# Specifying one of base class template parameters by derived class template parameter. How to use base class's using declarations

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have the next code:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
class a
{
public:
    using myfl_t = float;

    a(myfl_t fl, double db) {}

    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "a::f()\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class b : public a<T, int>
{
    using base_t = a<T, int>;
    using myfl_t = typename base_t::myfl_t;
public:
    b(myfl_t fl, double db)
        : base_t(fl, db) {}

    void f() override
    {
        std::cout << "b::f()\n";
    }
};
```

It seems that I can reuse the base class's  myfl_t declaration only by duplicating using in the derived class. 
Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Not sure if it is a dupe but explains why you have to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template

Comment: Since `myfl_t` dosn't depend on template parameter, you can move this symbol outside template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myflt_t` defined in `class a` is not visible in `class b` as explained here: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates

You can bring `myflt_t` into `class b` by without the explicit re-declaration:

```
using typename base_t::myfl_t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `using` in `b` and use this in the constructor:

```
b(typename a<T, int>::myfl_t fl, double db)
```

In any event, your current code seems fine to me. You aren't really duplicating anything here. Duplicating would be if you had to specify `float` again, which is not the case here, so it's fine.

See this for the reason why:

[Why is the keyword "typename" needed before qualified dependent names, and not before qualified independent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584431/why-is-the-keyword-typename-needed-before-qualified-dependent-names-and-not-b)