# What are second <> after function name in template funciton declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In a Stroustrup "A Tour of C++" he wrote example of find_all as

```
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> find_all(C& c, V v)
// find all occurrences of v in c
{
vector<typename C::iterator> res;
for (auto p = c.begin(); p!=c.end(); ++p)
if (∗p==v)
res.push_back(p);
return res;
}
```

What is `typename C::iterator` in  `template<typename C, typename V>  vector<typename C::iterator> find_all`? I haven't seen <> being both before and after function name. What is this construction and how it words?
In book he wrote

```
The typename is needed to inform the compiler that C’s iterator is supposed to be a type and not a
value of some type, say, the integer 7. We can hide this implementation detail by introducing a type
alias (§6.4.2) for Iterator:
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
// T’s iterator
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v)
// find all occurrences of v in c
{
...
```

Which doesn't make things clearer. I understand what `using Iterator = typename T::iterator;` is, but it doesn't explain second <> usage.

Comment: This is called a "template". Templates are something that take up multiple chapters to fully explain, in every C++ textbook. Giving you the answer by copy/pasting those chapters into Stackoverflow is not going to be very productive. So, you'll have to be referred to your C++ textbook for more details and explanation.

Comment: Note that the book you chose is not a beginner's introduction. It's more "a tour of new language features for the experienced pre-C++11 programmer". If you don't already know C++, you will struggle making sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename C, typename V> //template declaration
vector<typename C::iterator> //return type (vector of iterators)
find_all //function name
(C& c, V v) //argument list
```

Function `find_all` returns `vector<typename C::iterator>`, or "vector of iterators to C".

The reason why `typename` is needed is explained in this question: [Why is the keyword “typename” needed before qualified dependent names, and not before qualified independent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584431/why-is-the-keyword-typename-needed-before-qualified-dependent-names-and-not-b)

---

A simpler example, without templates, which also uses `<>` in return type:

```
std::vector<int> generateNNumbers(std::size_t numberOfElements)
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    ...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Oh, conctruction typename C::iterator confused ,e that much that I even didn't realize that it's part of the return value. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'ts interesting that I can add some restriction to the template type by writing something like C::iterator

Comment: @Johy Well, it is some restriction, but the point is that `find_all` expects that class `C` will have an internal type or typedef called `iterator` (which is visible publicly). It will then return a vector of that type to the caller.

Comment: And in the accepted answer from the link you provided in the example there is a line T::template C<int> z; Can you please tell what is T::template?

Comment: @Johy It's `T::(template C)<int> z`. It's not some special construct, it adds `template` keyword before name `C`. I believe explanation should also be in that answer? Side note: having 3 years professional experience in C++, I never found use for that. It's an obscure part of templates metaprogramming.